# Portfolio Filter for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am in the process of making my co's website on a wordpress theme and I have a slight bit of a problem. By default the category filter open 'all' even if a particular product is selected.

I am not well versed in php, and  would like to sort out this issue. Here is the link for your reference. http://test.danubewelfarecenter.com/four-columns/wall-panel/.

The support team for the theme is not really giving us any help. Would be grateful if you could help us. If we select any product from the main navigation menu, we would like the page to open with the filtered results than the default "all". However, the  category filters must not be removed from the page and can be used to filter other products as well.

Comment: use this plugin for portfolio filter: http://wordpress.org/plugins/awesome-filterable-portfolio/screenshots/

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you be able to let me know what if change has to be done to this code : afp-active-cat in the style sheet to make the selected category open?